# Coding Standards for button click event

Tags: c#, coding-style, idioms, solid-principles

I'm trying to follow good coding standards when attaching code to the default button click event.  Two options are:  Include several lines of code within the Click event handler **or** include a method that ultimately does same thing as those lines of code.

What are software design principles, or the concrete reasoning behind why I would use one way or the other?

*[additionally, it's an existing standard winforms application that is just getting extended a bit.]*

**Option A:**

```
private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var FileName = getFileName(reportPrefix);

    if (fileName == null)            
    {
        return;
    }

    SaveFile(fileName, QueryString);
}
```

**Option B:**

```
private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoExport();           
}


private void DoExport()
{
    var FileName = getFileName(reportPrefix);

    if (fileName == null)            
    {
        return;
    }

    SaveFile(fileName, QueryString);

}
```

Comment: If you need to use `DoExport` in more than one location, then Option B makes more sense.

Comment: use MVVM and bind to a command on your viewmodel.  https://www.codeproject.com/articles/238657/how-to-use-commands-in-wpf

Comment: Did OP mention he was using WPF?

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby he didn't mention any technology. wpf or winforms. but did mention solid-principles and i made the assumption of wpf or some sort of mvvm pattern which is available in winforms.

Comment: Option B, if winforms. If MVVM, Option B in the rare cases when you should be writing event handlers at all.

Comment: It is quite a brood question. Too broad even maybe. It also depends whether you want to bring the code under unit tests. Unit testing forms and buttons requires dependency injection support etc. If only architecture consists of two options.....

Comment: It's an old WinForms only application with no option to bring into WPF or any web technology.

Comment: your only option is B. but that doesn't get you to SOLID principles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will recommend for option B for following reasons:

1. **Separation of Concern**: The code that is handling the event (EventHandler) or delegate is *Separated* from the Actual implementation logic that does the actual work and is encapsulated in another method.
2. The intent of method `DoExport` is clear from it's name. If Someone read your code, it would be interpreted as

   **Option B:** *"When button is clicked Do export."*
   **Option A:** *"When button is clicked read the file name, if fileName is 
    empty then return, else Save the file."*

   Which sounds easier to Read?  For Readability purpose Option B provided a clear and concise way of representing your intentions.
3. If you decide to change the `button` to another control like anchor, linkButton, Label or any other control, you don't need to bind the event handler with the implementation details. Like the `DoExport` method shouldn't rely on the `EventArgs' or the`sender` objects.
4. In the future, the Export functionality (`DoExport`) needs to be called from other places in your code. Then, you can easily call the `DoExport` Method.
5. **Testing:** If you have this method as public and you want to test it. It is much easier to test the method rather than writing code to raise an event and then test the functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Neither, but B is closer than A:

SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) would recommend that you would separate business logic from the UI and not just at a method level, but **at least a class level** (a namespace and/or library level separation might be useful too). This is because the UI is likely to change independently of changes in export logic.

The UI class that contains `btnExport_Click` is responsible for driving the UI, showing data to the user and routing user interactions like clicks back to the business logic.

And another class entirely, preferably behind an abstraction, an interface is ideal (DIP, Dependency Inversion Principle), is responsible for exporting:

```
public class YouUIClass
{
    IExporter exporter;

    private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var fileName = GetFileName(reportPrefix);

        if (fileName == null)            
        {
            return;
        }
        exporter.DoExport(fileName);           
    }
}

public class Exporter : IExporter
{
    public void DoExport(string fileName)
    {
        SaveFile(fileName, queryString);
    }
}
```

(You may need to pass some arguments, like `filename` or `queryString` from the UI to the exporter method as I have demonstrated because I assume `GetFileName` is UI).

One massive advantage is you can test drive the business logic, without a UI involved. Manual tests are then just checking the UI is forwarding the events correctly to subsequent layers.

When it comes to decoupling the UI in this way, there are some patterns you can follow around this approach rather than rolling your own, patterns like MVC, MVP & MVVM.

Comment: Everybody's somewhere with filling in the knowledge gaps. :)

Comment: Sure :) well I would recommend you fill in some SOLID gaps with some content from Uncle Bob: http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod